# Not able to figure out issue in jest code coverage

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I have below file in my nestjs.

```
import { extname } from 'path';
import { diskStorage } from 'multer';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';

export const multerConfig = {
    dest: process.env.UPLOAD_LOCATION,
};

export const multerOptions = {
    limits: {
        fileSize: +process.env.MAX_FILE_SIZE,
    },
    fileFilter: (_req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
        if (file.mimetype.match(/\/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf|msg|eml)$/)) {
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb(
                new HttpException(
                    `Unsupported file type ${extname(file.originalname)}`,
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
                ),
                false
            );
        }
    },
    storage: diskStorage({
        destination: multerConfig.dest,
        filename: (_req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
            cb(null, `${uuid()}${extname(file.originalname)}`);
        },
    }),
};
```

I wrote below test cases for it.

```
import { Readable } from 'stream';
import { multerConfig, multerOptions } from './multer.config';

describe('Multer Configuration ', () => {
    const mockFile: Express.Multer.File = {
        filename: '',
        fieldname: '',
        originalname: '',
        encoding: '',
        mimetype: '',
        size: 1,
        stream: new Readable(),
        destination: '',
        path: '',
        buffer: Buffer.from('', 'utf8'),
    };
    it('should define destination', () => {
        expect(multerConfig).toBeDefined();
        expect(multerConfig.dest).toBe(process.env.UPLOAD_LOCATION);
    });

    it('should define multer upload options', async () => {
        expect(multerOptions).toBeDefined();
        expect(multerOptions.fileFilter).toBeDefined();
        expect(multerOptions.storage).toBeTruthy();
        expect(multerOptions.limits).toBeTruthy();

        const cb = jest.fn();
        multerOptions.fileFilter({}, mockFile, cb);
        expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(cb()).toBeFalsy();
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks();
    });
});
```

Both the test cases are successful but when I check code coverage then it is showing only 50% .It is showing line `16` and `31` not covered.

[image]

Line 16 is

```
 cb(null, true); it comes inside the `if` block
```

and line 31 is

```
 cb(null, `${uuid()}${extname(file.originalname)}`);
```

Could you please help me how can I cover this part? I am really struggling.
Do I need to additional test case or I need to modify the existing test case?

Edit 1:-

```
 const fileType = 'jpg';

    it('should define filetype', async () => {
        const cb = jest.fn();
        process.env.FILE_TYPE = 'jpg';
        multerOptions.fileFilter({}, mockFile, cb);
        expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(cb()).toBeFalsy();
    });
```

Test case getting success. but coverage and lines are still same

Comment: Please change the title so that future searchers can benefit from it. Imagine what would you put in a search engine if you had that problem?

Comment: Also note that code coverage has nothing to do with the number of tests passing. It tells you what pieces of code were covered by the tests.

Comment: sure I will do that. any help regarding testing that line?

Comment: Even small help or suggestion would be really helpful. please help

Comment: Node.JS now has built-in function for generating random GUIDs, so you probably don't need to use the 'uuid' library. Consider switching to `import {randomUUID} from 'crypto'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first not covered part of the code comes from the fact that you use pattern matching on the mime type.

```js
if (file.mimetype.match(/\/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf|msg|eml)$/)) {
            cb(null, true);
}
```

So you need to create a test that creates a mock file with one of those mime types.

For example, something like below. Although, in a good test setup, you probably would want to test all those extensions as a test case. Maybe with some sort of table driven test approach.

```js
const mockFile: Express.Multer.File = {
        mimetype: 'jpg',
        // other stuff 
};
```

It seems that in your test, the function always goes into the else block, which raises an HTTP Exception.

Your second issue is that you don't use options.storage, in your tests. And you also provide the options to something that would make the function get called.

Potentially, you can call it like below in your test.

```js
const upload = multer(multerOptions).single('somefile');
```

If you don't want to do that, you could move the callback into a named function and assign it.

```
export function filename(_req: any, file: any, cb: any) {
    cb(null, `${uuid()}${extname(file.originalname)}`);
}

export const multerOptions = {
    storage: diskStorage({
        destination: multerConfig.dest,
        filename,
    }),
}
```

Then you can test the filename function on its own in your test setup.

Or you find a way to call the filename function on the storage object on its own. I don't know `multer`, so I cannot tell if it is possible. You would need to consult the documentation.

In total this might look like this.

```
import { extname } from 'path';
import { diskStorage } from 'multer';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';

export const multerConfig = {
    dest: process.env.UPLOAD_LOCATION,
};

export function filename(_req: any, file: any, cb: any) {
            cb(null, `${uuid()}${extname(file.originalname)}`);
};

export const multerOptions = {
    limits: {
        fileSize: +process.env.MAX_FILE_SIZE,
    },
    fileFilter: (_req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
        if (file.mimetype.match(/\/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf|msg|eml)$/)) {
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb(
                new HttpException(
                    `Unsupported file type ${extname(file.originalname)}`,
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
                ),
                false
            );
        }
    },
    storage: diskStorage({
        destination: multerConfig.dest,
        filename,
    }),
};
```

And then in your test like this.

```
import { Readable } from 'stream';
import { multerConfig, multerOptions, filename } from './multer.config';

describe('Multer Configuration ', () => {
    const mockFile: Express.Multer.File = {
        filename: 'foo.jpg', // give it a name
        fieldname: '',
        originalname: '',
        encoding: 'utf8',
        mimetype: 'jpg', // give it a mime type
        size: 1,
        stream: new Readable(),
        destination: '',
        path: '',
        buffer: Buffer.from('', 'utf8'),
    };
    it('should define destination', () => {
        expect(multerConfig).toBeDefined();
        expect(multerConfig.dest).toBe(process.env.UPLOAD_LOCATION);
    });

    it('should define multer upload options', async () => {
        expect(multerOptions).toBeDefined();
        expect(multerOptions.fileFilter).toBeDefined();
        expect(multerOptions.storage).toBeTruthy();
        expect(multerOptions.limits).toBeTruthy();
    });
    
    // test the filter
    it('should filter the file based on mimetype', () => {
        const cb = jest.fn();
        multerOptions.fileFilter({}, mockFile, cb);
        // do something with the callback
    });
    
    // test the filename
    it('should create the proper filename', () => {
        const cb = jest.fn();
        filename({}, mockfile, cb)
        // do something with the callback
    });


    afterAll(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks();
    });
});
```

I am not sure how to use jest or what you actually want to test. But like this, the line should get covered. But coverage doesn't mean much in that sense. The tests like this are not good. You should work out what precisely you want to test. This is just to show you wants roughly required.

Comment: thank you. how to incorporate tha filetype changes in test cases? because I did same but still same line is coming and it is not showing in coverage.

Comment: @Oze, what do you mean by filetype?

Comment: Hi, I have added my code which I have written at the end of question. I have edited the code

Comment: You need to initialize your mock file with the correct values. From your update, it seems like you setting an environment variable.  You should set `mockFile.mimetype = 'jpg'` before you call `multerOptions.fileFilter({}, mockFile, cb);`

Comment: the filter will check the mime type. If your mock file doesnt have one, you end up in the else block.

Comment: so can you suggest the changes on the same line?

Comment: I am actually very new. I need to deliver code so struggling

Comment: @Oze, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Test cases passed, but coverage is still same. those lines still not covered.

Comment: perhaps your matcher is off `/\/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf|msg|eml)$/`, why do you have the slash in the beginning? It should maybe look like this `/^(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf|msg|eml)$/` Also it cant be the same since the function has moved. Something must have changed about the filename coverage.

Comment: sure I will check that.thank you so much

Comment: Thank you so much . you spotted correctly. Matcher was not working correctly.